# how to add dynamic fields with values entered in advance?

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to dynamically add a few fields for example 30. 30 rows. that I have a field with which number the row starts and that number increases for example by 5 on each following row?

All code is on stackblitz: this is only little example

```
addTimedExerciseSets(data){
    console.log('data' , data);
    for (let index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
      this.addSet(data)
   }
 }
```

How to get to this ( UI ). Select a value from the drop-down menu. Click on the name of that exercise. I see it as a table with those values.

See also html but again all code is on stackbltiz:

```
<span *ngIf="trainingTemplateExercises.data.isTest">
  <input class="select form-control disabled-select unset-block" placeholder="Začetna teža" type="text" [(ngModel)]="startWeight">
</span>

<span *ngIf="trainingTemplateExercises.data.isTest">
  <input class="select form-control disabled-select unset-block" placeholder="Stopnevanje teže" type="text" [(ngModel)]="stopTimesRepetititon">
</span>
<span *ngIf="trainingTemplateExercises.data.isTest">
   <button (click)="addTimedExerciseSets(trainingTemplateExercises.data)">add</button>
</span>
```

I want to [(ngModel)]="set.value" in loop if i write 10 first value be 10. if I set stopTimesRepetititon 5 10 - 15 - 20 - 25 - 30 - 35...

Stakblitz code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-devextrem-nm9dod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

example:

```
1. row 
2. row
3. row
4. row...
....
30. row

input 50 for start
increment by 5
table now look like a 
1.row = 50
2.row = 55
3.row = 60
4.row = 65
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i add thirty reps with starting weight and increasing values by 5 or 10? Using for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422660/how-do-i-add-thirty-reps-with-starting-weight-and-increasing-values-by-5-or-10)

Comment: No this is not same

Comment: You changed it a little, but it is the same. Asking the same question over and over again will earn you a suspension on SO.